# Multi level subfolders in a site

Tags: subdirectory, multi-level

How can I access a file in a web-directory which is two levels up. For example, if an image file is found in a folder images one-level up, I can access it using ../images/filename.jpg. But, if the file is in a folder found two-level up, how can I access it. I tried using three, four, five and six dots but it just doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For every folder you want go back you should use ../
so if there is 2 folders back you just do it twice ../../
and on like that 
../../../
how many you want

but remember you can't go anywhere you want so there is an access limit sometimes

Comment: Many thanks! It works. I am just a new bee and still learning lots of staff.